# How to programmatically change the mass/inertia of a link from an ignition-fortress plugin?

Tags: gazebo-plugin, ignition-fortress, gazebo-plugins

I'm trying to dynamically update the mass of a link, during execution, from a gazebo ignition-fortress plugin. Specifically, I'd like to update the link's mass to a small value. What is the right C++ API to do this? I know I am not providing many details, but the goal is very simple: set the mass of a link. Thanks in advance!